# Do browsers support global references to html elements named by id?

Tags: javascript, html, css, cross-browser

I accidentally typed the following code in JavaScript and it worked:

```js
my_element.addEventListener("click", function() {
  alert("Hello world");  
})
```

```css
#my_element {
  background: lightblue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="my_element">hello there</div>
```

I did not get the element using:

```
var element = document.getElementById("my_element");
```

I simply referenced the element like so and it worked!?!

```
my_element.addEventListener("click", function() {
  alert("Hello world");  
})
```

This works in Firefox and Chrome. I have not tested in other browsers. Is this well known? Is this fully supported in browsers?

I have always returned a reference to the HTML element. My shock is that I can simply type the ID of the element as if it was a global object!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's universally supported, and it's even now [in the HTML5 specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/window-object.html#named-access-on-the-window-object). Automatic global variables are created for every element with an `id` (and many others with `name`s).

I never rely on it, there are too many other things in the global namespace. But yes, it's defined behavior.

---

In a comment below you asked what happens when there's a conflict. More in [my answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63178138/can-i-clarify-the-terminology-of-the-global-scope-global-objects-the-global-ob/63178497#63178497), but there's an order to it. Automatic DOM globals are shadowed by declared global variables, in a couple of different ways. Here's an example:

```js
// `example1` is a DOM automatic global
console.log(typeof example1);                                        // object
console.log("example1" in this);                                     // true
console.log(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(this, "example1")); // false

// We have both a DOM element with `example2` as its ID and also a
// `var`-declared global; the latter takes precedence
var example2;
console.log(typeof example2);                                        // undefined
console.log("example2" in this);                                     // true
console.log(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(this, "example2")); // true

// We have a DOM element with `example3` as its ID, a global object property
// with that name, and also a `let`-declared global variable; the latter wins
this.example3 = 42;
let example3;
console.log(typeof example3);                                        // undefined
console.log("example3" in this);                                     // true
console.log(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(this, "example3")); // true
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="example1"></div>
<div id="example2"></div>
<div id="example3"></div>
```

---

In a further comment you asked:

> What of the case of conflicts with existing global members? For example, if I name my element "window" or "document"? Will my element take precedents over the existing global object member?

No, `window` and `document` and [others](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/window-object.html#the-window-object) are **own properties** of the Window object, but the automatic DOM globals are on its prototype (on compliant browsers; not IE11 or IIRC Legacy Edge). So its own properties win. To get at the automatic DOM globals, you'd have to go to `window`'s prototype:

```js
// `window` here is still the global object
console.log(window === this);                              // true
var someVariableName;
console.log("someVariableName" in window);                 // true

// The automatic DOM global "window" is on its prototype:
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(window).window.tagName); // "DIV"
```

```html
<div id="window"></div>
```

Of course, **none** of this is behavior you want to rely on. If you want to access a DOM element by its `id`, use `getElementById` (or `querySelector` or similar).

Comment: Then the next question is do these automatic global members overwrite existing global properties or does it fail (silently or loudly) when naming conflicts occur?

Comment: @1.21gigawatts - It *succeeds* silently, and not always in the way one expects. :-) The globals created for DOM elements are inherited properties of the global object (on modern browsers), so if you declare a variable with `var` at global scope (which creates an "own" property of the global object), that takes precedence over the automatic global. If you declare a variable with `let` or `const` at global scope, that's created on the inner global scope (which isn't connected to the global object), so it takes precedence over an automatic global or a global object property.

Comment: @1.21gigawatts - More here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63178138/can-i-clarify-the-terminology-of-the-global-scope-global-objects-the-global-ob/63178497#63178497

Comment: (I've also added examples to the answer.)

Comment: What of the case of conflicts with existing global members? For example, if I name my element "window" or "document"? Will my element take precedents over the existing global object member?

Comment: @1.21gigawatts - Updated for that, too. (FWIW, it's "precedence" rather than "precedents.")